# Monthly data with carbon in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to get registered users count by the month and not days.

## example

If I have such code:

```
$newUsers = User::where('created_at', '<=', now()->subdays(30))->count();
```

it will return users from last 30 days, imagine today is `15th` of the month so the result will be from last month `15th` till this month `15th`

> This is not what I want!

What I want is to count users from `1st` of the month until `30`

That means if today is `15` I get users count from `1st` to `15` and nothing from last month.

**How to get that?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `whereMonth()` function for query builder in laravel.

```
$usersCount = User::whereMonth(
    'created_at',
    Carbon::now()->format('m')
)->count();
```

**Edit**

to match the exact month (month with year)

```
$usersCount = User::whereMonth(
    'created_at',
    Carbon::now()->format('m')
)->whereYear(
    'created_at',
    Carbon::now()->format('Y')
)->count();
```

Comment: Will this not also count records of last year(s) with the same month? I suggest adding a `whereYear()` as well.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan do you want to update your answer? :)